# ' I went to place that I wanted to go to'

Tags: infinitives

' I went to place that I wanted to go to'

I've just read the sentence above from some test papers, and it looked really awkward.

I've already heard "I went to the place where I wanted to go" sounds more natural.

by the way, it was a test, 
and it was the case like I must use a relative pronoun 'that',
Could I say "I went to the place that I want to go"  instead of saying " I went to the place that I want to go to"  just without 'to'?

If it's possible to say like that(saying without to), please let me know how grammatically it works

Comment: The main reason that the first sentence is awkward is that it is missing an article _the_ before _place_. For the rest, it is fine. Changing _wanted_ to _want_ makes the sentence really strange - you went there, and you still want to go there? And no, you shouldn't leave out the _to_; you could form a sentence without a preposition like _I went where I wanted_, but that is quite a different sentence altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds better to say "I went to that place, I really wanted to go."

Comment: to* you should add 'to' as it sounds more grammatical

Answer (score 1):

As someone already pointed out, the only issue with the first sentence is the absence of the article "the" before the noun "place". It should read:

> I went to THE place that/which/- I wanted to go to.

Concerning the second example, it is semantically the same but syntactically different as "where" is acting as a relative adverb--that also why you don't need the preposition TO after the verb "go".

So, you either use an object-relative pronoun (which/that or none) for the verb GO followed by its preposition TO. Or, you use the relative adverb "where" with the verb GO with no preposition (since the relative clause will no longer be referring to the object of the preposition 'TO', but the adverbial of place).